# Java 9 Services - iterate through provider classes?

Tags: java, java-9

I am trying to create a service in Java 9 (Java 11 really) that has multiple providers, in this case a DatabaseConnection service.

What I expect to be able to do (Please correct me if I am totally not understanding services at some fundamental level):

- Iterate through the registered Providers and find a class to instantiate based on an annotation (such as `@DBC(engine="mssql")`)
- Find an existing object by an internal name or identifier it is assigned after instantiation (such as iterating through the instantiated objects and calling get name)

For starters, how can I iterate through the Provider classes, so I can check an annotation that indicates which engine each provider uses, without instantiating anything? As far as I can tell, stream() should return a stream of Providers that I can iterate through and check the annotations on, but stream().size() returns 0.

Second, how do I iterate through the instantiated providers? iterator() looks like it should do this, but according to the documentation it instantiates every provider that hasn't been instantiated yet.

This is my Service:

```
public interface DatabaseConnection
{
    void init(String connectionString, String internalName, String username, String password);
    String getName();
    String query();
}
```

This is one of my providers:

```
@DBC(engine="mssql")
public class MSSQLDatabaseConnection implements DatabaseConnection
{
  public void init(String connectionString, String internalName, String username, String password)
  {
    this.internalName = internalName;
    connect(connectionString, username, password);
  }
  public String getName()
  {
    return internalName;
  }
  public String query()
  {
    //Does stuff
  }
  public void connect()
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is my module-info:

```
module my.libs.database {
    uses DatabaseConnection;
    exports my.libs.database;
    exports my.libs.database.util;
    exports my.libs.database.api;
    exports my.libs.database.exception;
    requires java.sql;
    requires com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc;

    provides DatabaseConnection with MSSQLDatabaseConnection, TestDatabaseConnection;
}
```

Finally, in my main class, I tried getting a stream but don't get anything returned:

```
ServiceLoader<DatabaseConnection> dbcs = ServiceLoader.load(DatabaseConnection.class);
Stream<ServiceLoader.Provider<DatabaseConnection>> test1 = dbcs.stream();
System.out.println("Found " + test1.count() + " classes");
```

Output `Found 0 classes`

Comment: Your code and module descriptor look correct.  Are you sure the module containing the providers is in the module path?  Note that the classpath is ignored when running modules.

Comment: @VGR Does any documentation supports the argument *classpath is ignored when running modules*?

Comment: @VGR the providers are in the same module as the service and the main class I am using to test, the service itself in a package api, the providers in the package engines

Comment: @Wige Strange.  count() should not return zero.  It’s fine to use `dbcs.iterator()`;  that method always returns all available providers.  The documentation states that the providers may be lazily loaded, but it will never skip any of them.  In fact, since ServiceLoader implements Iterable, you can just do `for (DatabaseConnection dbc : dbcs)` instead of referencing an Iterator explicitly.

Comment: @Naman From the [Module paths](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Module-paths) section of JEP 261: “…the module system locates a module by searching along several different paths…: • The compilation module path … (compile time only). • The upgrade module path … • The system modules … • The application module path (`--module-path`, or `-p` for shore) …”

Comment: @Naman From the [Jar File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/jar/jar.html): “A modular JAR file deployed on the module path, as opposed to the class path, is an explicit module.”

Comment: I tried the `for (DatabaseConnection dbc : dbcs)` but got no output, so I called iterator().size() which gave me 0. From what I saw in the documentation, calling next() returns an object of the provider, rather than the provider itself.